# JSON encode MySQL results then read using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a database table with some rows that I want to fetch using PHP and then encode them using JSON.

Currently, my database structure is the following:

```
idcomponente | quantidade
```

After fetching the values in PHP, I want to know how can I encode them using JSON (with multiple rows, using the same names) so I can read them using `jQuery.post()`.

```
$.post('test.php',{id:id},function(data){
    //READ data HERE
});
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

So far, I made this:

```
$.post('edit/producomponentes.php',{id:id},function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Logs this:

```
[Object { componente="1", quantidade="2"}, Object { componente="3", quantidade="3"}]
```

Now how can I go through each row and fetch their properties? (data.componente, data.quantidade)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I try to give you some idea.

Make associative array in PHP using `key => value` pair like

```
$data = array('id' => 1, 'quat' => 10, 'id' => 2, 'quat' => 20)
```

and then send it as **[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** like

```
header('Content-type: application/json');  // don't miss it
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```

***In jQuery***

```
$.post('edit/producomponentes.php',{id:id},function(response){
    //READ data HERE.
    console.log(response.data); // you will get a json Object
}, 'json');
     ^-------- set dataType as json, then you don't any extra parse effort
```

#### According to edit

```
 $.post('edit/producomponentes.php',{id:id},function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
           console.log(value.componente);
           console.log(value.quantidade);
        });
    }, 'json');
```

Comment: Dont forget to set the correct headers in the php file to serve JSON :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I already have the headers, now my only question is how to loop through the rows (see edited post).

Answer (score 2):

In test.php

```
$id = $_POST['id']; // if is 'id' passed to fetch one row
$db = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB_NAME);
$q = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $db->query($q);
```

**EDIT** proper headers to for json responses

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
$result->close();
$db->close();
```

In JavaScript

```
$.post('test.php',{id:id},function(data){
    console.log(data); // data is already a js object
},'json'); // specify the data type you expect
```

Comment: PHP side is complete, now I need to loop through the rows in jQuery (see edited post). Thanks

Comment: is the `header()` `Cache-Control` and `Expires` really necessary?

Comment: not really but prevent browser from caching responses which is something you dont want with ajax responses

Answer (score 1):

use JSON.parse to get the data as an object like

```
var object1 = JSON.parse(data);
alert(object1.property1);
```

for encoding on php, use

```
json_encode($result); //assuming you're getting a result set.
```

to encode your result set and

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

to print it to document body, so that you can fetch using jquery on result data

documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

you'll need to test it many times, be patient and chech your values with echo on the php side and alert() with the client side.

Comment: My question is (using PHP), how to encode multiple rows with the same name correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You could place each row in an array and run `json_encode()` on the final array to get one big JSON object.

Reference - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php