# My sql content to javascript array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays

This is code taken from dynamic drive .com for Pausing up-down Scroller (text animation):

How can i take the texts from a mysql table instead of giving as an array so that i can change the content accodirngly.

```
var pausecontent=new Array()
pausecontent[0]='<a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a><br />Comprehensive JavaScript tutorials and over 400+ free scripts!'
pausecontent[1]='<a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a><br />Web coding and development forums.'
pausecontent[2]='<a href="http://www.cssdrive.com" target="_new">CSS Drive</a><br />Categorized CSS gallery and examples.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your mysql result into a JSON object using this,

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
 $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

and this result can be accessed using ajax requests.

You will get an idea on displaying the encoded results from here [JSON encode MySQL results then read using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116009/json-encode-mysql-results-then-read-using-jquery)

Comment: Hai prasanth its not working for me......it is just printing the whole mysql column content......

how to use ion java script,i tried like this..is it correct 
var pausecontent=json_encode();

Answer (score 0):

what about this code?

```
<?php
$server_name="localhost";
    $db_user="sql_user";
    $db_pass="password";
$db="mydb";
mysql_connect($server_name, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db);


$sql = "SELECT text FROM posts";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Query Error: ' . mysql_error());

while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($result))
$texts[] = $results;}

?>


<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div> 

 <script type="text/javascript">

  var pausecontent = document.getElementById("<?=$texts?>");
```

Comment: what is the difference between this code and method using Json?

which code is better........?